# Making a module based social networking cms

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, content-management-system, social-networking

What does it take to create a social networking cms like phpfox or socialengine .

I am interested in using php / mysql .

However , I want it to be modular , like above examples . Like I can enable disable videos from backend .

Most important , it should have ability to allow others to extend it , like facebook applications .

Should I follow a framework  [ cakephp or something ]?

Should I use some pattern [ factory or singleton ] ?

Is there any book available on subject ?

Comment: There is no difference between such a CMS and any other mid-size web application. The only things you need are education and experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a book [PHP5 CMS Framework Development](http://www.ebook3000.com/PHP-5-CMS-Framework-Development_22419.html)